# Evans pde book: details on an bound for a Sobolev norm in the proof of the Meyers-Serrin theorem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, proof-verification, sobolev-spaces

Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f\in W^{m,p}(U)$. Suppose that
$$\|f\|_{W^{m,p}(V)}\leq\delta\tag{1}$$
for all $V\subset\subset U$ (that is, all $V$ such that $V\subset\overline{V} \subset U$ with $\overline{V}$ compact). My problem is to show that
$$\|f\|_{W^{m,p}(U)}\leq\delta\tag{2}.$$

[Evans book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=5Pv4LVB_m8AC&redir_esc=y) (p. 252) says that $(2)$ is obtained by taking the supremum in $(1)$ over sets $V\subset\subset U$ and [Leoni's book](https://books.google.com.br/books/about/A_First_Course_in_Sobolev_Spaces.html?id=W3RLWwnY0RkC&redir_esc=y) (p. 285), as well as the [original paper](http://www.pnas.org/content/51/6/1055.full.pdf), by applying the Lebesgue monotone convergence theorem. However, none of them gives the details. **So, I'd like to know if the proof below is correct.**

> Take a sequence of sets $\{V_{k}\}_{k=1}^\infty$ such that
>
> - $V_k\subset\subset U$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$;
> - $V_k\subset V_{k+1}$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$;
> - $U=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} V_k$.
>
> Fix $\alpha$ such that $|\alpha|\leq m$. For each $k\in\mathbb{N}$, define $f_k:U\to\mathbb{R}$ by setting $f_k(x)=|D^\alpha f(x)|^p$ if $x\in V_k$, and $f_k(x)=0$ if $x\in U\setminus V_k$. We have
>   $$0\leq f_k(x)\leq f_{k+1}(x)$$
>   for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and all $x\in U$. Furthermore,
>   $$\lim_{k\to\infty} f_k(x)=|D^\alpha f(x)|^p$$
>   for all $x\in U$.
>   Thus, by the Lebesgue monotone convergence theorem,
>   $$\|D^\alpha f\|_{L^p(U)}^p=\int_U|D^\alpha f(x)|^p\; dx=\int_U\lim_{k\to\infty}f_k(x)\; 
> dx=\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{U}f_k(x)\; dx$$
>   $$=\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{V_k}f_k(x)\; dx=\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{V_k}|D^\alpha f(x)|^p\; dx=\lim_{k\to\infty}\|D^\alpha f\|_{L^p(V_k)}^p.$$
>   Summing with respect to $\alpha$, we obtain
>   $$\|f\|_{W^{m,p}(U)}^p=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq m}\|D^{\alpha}f\|_{L^p(U)}^p= \sum_{|\alpha|\leq m} \lim_{k\to\infty}\|D^\alpha f\|_{L^p(V_k)}^p=\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{|\alpha|\leq m} \|D^\alpha f\|_{L^p(V_k)}^p$$
>   $$=\lim_{k\to\infty}\|f\|_{W^{m,p}(V_k)}^p\leq \delta^p.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proof looks correct to me, well done!

A couple of nitpicks: in the definition of $V \subset \subset U$ you forgot to include that $\overline{V}$ needs to be compact; the very last $\delta$ should be $\delta^p$.

The only thing that I would like to add is an explicit definition for $V_k$: $$V_k := \Big\{x \in U : \text{dist}(x, \partial U) > \frac{1}{k}\Big\} \cap B(0,k)$$

Comment: Thank you for the corrections and the example. I corrected the errors. In the example, the intersection with the ball is to ensure that the closure is compact, right?

Comment: yes, that is exactly why the ball is there :)