# understanding the proof of global approximation theorem Evans PDE II

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

The proof is given in [understanding proof of global approximation theorem Evans PDE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2284341/understanding-proof-of-global-approximation-theorem-evans-pde). I can see what is going on in the proof, but I do not get the point of defining $V_i=U_{i+3}-\overline{U}_{i+1}$. I think it already works if we do the partition of unity subordinate just to $\{U_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$.