# Where I get video lectures of Sobolev spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

i am start studying Sobolev Spaces By the book name Partial Differential Equations  by Laerence C. Evans...

but while i am studying i have so many doubts and i asked one of my professor he said that either you give a lecture or you have to attend .. can you please some  one suggest me where i can get video lectures of Sobolev lectures please help me or  some one tell what is best to understand entire things i want to be learn each and everything in that...

thankyou to everyone ..please i need suggestion..

Comment: Well, for specific doubts, you can always ask questions on this forum...

Comment: @HansLundmark...thanks but i have one doubt then i can ask but im learner so i have plenty of  doubts....for example while i am studying Global approximation by smooth functions i have doubt with entire theorem..

Comment: @InverseProblem I don't know about lectures, but when I was studying sobolev spaces I found there [notes](https://math.aalto.fi/~jkkinnun/files/sobolev_spaces.pdf) very helpful!

Comment: @InverseProblem With respect to the theorem you mentioned, the last line of the proof is detailed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1409792/70305). You can find more details [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=global+approximation+evans).